# setup.py is not install dependencies

Tags: python, setup.py

I am trying to create a command line utility that can be installed via `pip install git+https://github.com/project/neat_util.git@master#egg=neat_util` and I am testing locally with  `python setup.py install`.

```
import os
import pathlib

import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="neat_util",
    version="1.0.0",
    author="Cogito Ergo Sum",
    author_email="cogito@ergo.sum",
    description="Util for utilization",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://gitlab.com/project/repo",
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3"
    ],
    package_dir={"": "bin"},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where="bin"),
    include_package_data=True,,
    dependency_links=['git+https://github.com/company/dependency.git@master#egg=dependency'],
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    scripts=['bin/neat_util']
)
```

When I test this locally, it installs fine and I can invoke it from the command line but I get a ModuleNotFoundError" No module named dependency error.

The github url appears to be correct based off of the documentation here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/ specifically `git+https://git.example.com/MyProject.git@master#egg=MyProject`

Running `pip install git+https://github.com/company/dependency.git@master#egg=dependency` actually works as well so I feel confident that the url isn't the issue.

Project structure:

```
├── bin
│   ├── script1
│   ├── script2
│   ├── script3
│   ├── neat_util
│   ├── script4
│   └── script5
├── collections.csv
├── config.cfg
├── config.cfg.example
├── env.sh
├── env.sh.example
├── example.csv
├── main.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests
```

Any pointers here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dependency_links` were declared obsolete and finally [removed](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) in `pip` 19.0. The replacement for it is `install_requires` with special syntax (supported since `pip` 19.1):

```
install_requires=[
    'dependency @ git+https://github.com/company/dependency.git@master',
]
```

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references

This requires `pip install` including `pip install .` and doesn't work with `python setup.py install`.